# WOPI host and WOPI client example

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, ms-wopi

I am a bit confused about WOPI host and WOPI client.
Can anyone tell me exactly the meaning of above 2 terms. I want to know what exactly means WOPI host (either my web application or a WOPI server on Microsoft side) and same for WOPI client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**WOPI host** = WOPI server = a web API that serves files to WOPI client

**WOPI client** = an application that is able to edit files served by WOPI host

The two communicate via MS-WOPI protocol that is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622722%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Example implementations:

- WOPI host - SharePoint
- WOPI client - Office Web Apps (Office Online Server)

A typical scenario is that you want to enable your application to edit files in Word/Excel... In that case, you need to implement a WOPI host - an endpoint which the WOPI client (OWA) will talk to. Implementing such a host is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh622722%28v=office.12%29.aspx).
You can take a look at existing projects on GitHub - [marx-yu's implementation using HttpListener](https://github.com/marx-yu/WopiHost), or [mine using ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://github.com/petrsvihlik/WopiHost).

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I would like to know one more thing about that Lock request,
There is nothing defined in Lock endpoint implementation document on http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/Lock.html

What should this request generate ?
Any random string or what ?

Comment: A random string that is within the following boundaries: http://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/concepts.html#lock-length

Comment: Got it boss!! Thanks. :)

Comment: Hi Rocky, that was a very good answer. I just want to ask that Is is possible to implement WOPI host in Node.js? Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: I saw you submitted a separate question. Check out my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062025/wopi-host-implementation-in-nodejs/39186295#39186295

Comment: Hi, rocky, could you give me some suggestions about this (problem)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540105/how-to-let-office-online-own-the-style-of-view-mode] Thanks.

Comment: @rocky is Office Web Apps free of cost?

Comment: Afaik, it's only free for viewing docs, not editing. The full licensing terms can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/licensing/how-to-license-office-web-apps-server

Comment: For Office Online Server (a newer version of OWA), see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server