# How to let office online own the style of view mode?

Tags: ms-wopi

Recently, I would like to use the “edit mode” of Office Online Server to open the Microsoft Word file as follows:

```
http://office-online/we/wordeditorframe.aspx?WOPISrc=...&access_token=...
```

However, I notice that there is no gap between two consecutive pages, please see the following screenshot.

[image]

In addition, when I use the “view mode” to view a word document with *wordviewframe.aspx*, the presentation of page is normal.

```
http://officeonline/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?WOPISrc=...&access_token=...
```

[image]

But this time I discover that the **Edit in Browser** button(in the top right-hand corner)cannot be used.

I have added the attributes such as

`HostEditUrl`, `EditModePostMessage` in `CheckFileInfo` described in official document.

[image]

[image]

So I have two questions:

1) How to let “edit mode” own the style of “view model”? Namely, there is some space between two word page.

2) How to switch to edit-mode from view mode?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be used"? Is the link disabled? Does it lead to a dead URL?

Comment: @rocky Yes, “cannot use” means the button is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This might actually be a bug in the OOS. Can you verify that the problem persists when you switch the [`<ui=UI_LLCC&><rs=DC_LLCC&>`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery.html) to English locale & open a document written in English? Just to rule out this possibility.

2) The `HostViewUrl` and `HostEditUrl` is supposed to lead to a ["host page"](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html#term-host-page) - an HTML page which will host an iframe that points to an Office for the web application. => Not to the OOS URL directly.

Answer (score 2):

Your WOPI host (your own API which implemented WOPI Protocol) must,

1. Implement methods [PutFile](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/PutFile.html#putfile) (to save updated file on your storage) and [PutRelativeFile](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/PutRelativeFile.html#putrelativefile) (to create a new file based on the current file, for example converting from .doc to be .docx).
2. Return following data in the response of [CheckFileInfo](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html) operation.
   2.1 *SupportUpdate : true* (to let WOPI Client know that your API implement the PutFile and PutRelativeFile methods)
   2.2 *UserCanWrite : true* (to indicate that the use have Write permission over the file)
   2.3 *LicenseCheckForEditIsEnabled : true* (to route user to Microsoft Login page to verify that the user have Office 365 license)
   2.4 *HostEditUrl : url_to_your_edit_page*

**NOTE:** Your user need MS Office 365 license in order to edit file on WOPI.
[image: Valid XHTML].